# how to get/set value of dynamically created text box

Tags: javascript, dynamic

i'm working on a holiday greeting card that behaves like fb in a very simple way and in the commenting portion, i can't seem to get and set the value of the dynamically created text box that appears after the user has added a new comment... i'm creating a new text field with an appended number for the id to identify it and i can set the value in the function that creates it, but once looking for it from another function, the code breaks.  any ideas?  i would figure that maybe this would be contingent on where the function occurs in the document but not sure about that.  here's a link:

[Elfbook](http://getpearson.com/nosesobright)

here it is in a nutshell:

comment() contains the following code that modifies the input field

`// var subject = 'HI593F1' or something like that;

// var current_comment = new Array() and keeps count of the current new comment box

// this resulting value looks like this: 'comment-HI593F1-2'

var comment_field = 'comment-'+subject+'-'+current_comment[subject];


document.getElementById(comment_field).value = 'Write a comment...';

document.getElementById(comment_field).onblur = function() { ghost('comment', subject); }

document.getElementById(comment_field).onfocus = function() { unghost('comment', subject); }

document.getElementById(comment_field).onkeypress = function() { text_color('comment', subject); }`

unghost() works like this:

```
function unghost(field, number)
    {
    // field = 'comment' ... this is 'comment' because this function modifies more than one field
    var ogfield = field;
    // if another comment is expanded
    if (current)
        {
        collapse_comment(current);
        }
    current = number;

    // like var comment field in the comment() function
    if (number)
        {
        field = field+"-"+number+"-"+current_comment[number];
        }

    // below is where the code breaks ... values[ogfield] = 'Write a comment...';
    // should look like this: document.getElementById('comment-HI593F1-2').value == 'Write a comment...'
    if (document.getElementById(field).value == values[ogfield])
        {
        document.getElementById(field).value = \'\';
        }

    // change the color of the field text
    text_color(field, number);
    }
```

Comment: Post relevant code and we shall see.

Comment: it is at the url provided... just view source

Comment: No I won't do that. Post relevant code here please, otherwise you can't really expect much help from people around here.

Comment: I realize this isn't really relevant, but I believe Facebook has a patent on what you're doing.  See http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_granted_patent_on_the_news_feed_-_this_co.php and the discussion at http://www.google.com/buzz/teamrww/8AWZna9r9YV/Facebook-has-been-granted-a-patent-on-the-Newsfeed.  Just a warning.

Comment: @Lucas I meant readable version of the code.. anyway please point us on the place where you create the text field and where you try to get it back later. Couldn't find it in quick look.

Comment: please review the updated code

Comment: I would strongly advise against modifying the passed parameter `field` in your `unGhost` routine. I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with it but it looks guaranteed to cause confusion at a later date.

Comment: Have you examined the executing code at the point of failure for example in Firebug and examined the values of the variables in question? Particularly `values`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in the expected value to the `text_color` method.

I've taken some of your code below. See the `onBlur` attribute of the input calls `ghost` with the two parameters. Below is the body of `ghost`, in it the `field` parameter is modified and then passed into `text_color` - which in turn modifies the value.

```
<input type="text" id="comment-MS584C7-1" value="Write a comment..." style="width: 386px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #c1dcc0; color: #666464; padding: 3px;" onBlur="ghost('comment', 'MS584C7');" onFocus="unghost('comment', 'MS584C7');" onkeypress="text_color('comment', 'MS584C7');" />


function ghost(field, number)
    {
    var ogfield = field;
    if (number)
        {
        field = field+"-"+number+"-"+current_comment[number];
        }
    if (!document.getElementById(field).value)
        {
        document.getElementById(field).value = values[ogfield];    
        }
    text_color(field, number); 
}
```

I would suggest creating a new `ognumber` variable to hold the original number value. Then pass `ogfield` and `ognumber` to `text_color`.

`unghost` suffers the same problem.

**EDIT**
I'm using Chrome, and here are the request headers sent when I click comment.

```
Request URL:http://getpearson.com/nosesobright_comment.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:90
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:PHPSESSID=------------------
Host:getpearson.com
Origin:http://getpearson.com
Referer:http://getpearson.com/nosesobright
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.215 Safari/534.10
Form Data
subject:MS584C7
user:XP192R5
name:
avatar:undefined
attachment:undefined
comment:asdasdasd
Response Headers
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:155
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 13 Dec 2010 23:42:31 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=30
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.14
```

The comment I entered is coming through.

Comment: i did a check and you are right about that... document.getElementById(comment_field).value, however, is not getting a value at all.

Comment: +1 Yes, I tried the code from the link and it failed within `text_color`